# La entrada debe aceptar un único carácter

Tags: c

Necesito que en una parte determinada de mi programa pueda ingresar un dato de tipo `char`, pero necesito que cumpla un requisito, y es que acepte **un único carácter**.

Por ejemplo, si yo hago:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void vacia_buffer_letra(){
    while (getchar() != '\n');
}

int main(){
    char c;
    printf("Ingrese una letra: \n");
    c=getchar();
    vacia_buffer_letra(); //borro el buffer
    if(c=='a'){
        printf("Esta bien");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Lo que necesito es que el programa entre **únicamente** al `if` cuando se ingrese por teclado `'a'` y que no ingrese cuando se escriba `aa`.

Comment: La función getchar(); toma todo lo que ingreses

Comment: Te amplío el significado del comentario de @SalvaCastro: como `getchar()` toma toda la cadena introducida, cuando tecleas `a` te pedirá la introducción de una segunda línea de texto debido a la llamada a `vacia_buffer_letra()` y si introduces `aa` pasará exactamente lo mismo porque `getchar()` se quedará únicamente con el primer carácter y el resto lo descarta, por lo que de nuevo `vacia_buffer_letra()` volverá a quedarse esperando que introduzcas algo. Echa un vistazo a mi respuesta para ver si te vale el método que te propongo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo estás planteando mal porque [`getchar()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) obtiene un único carácter por mucho texto que escribas, por lo que no detectará si has tecleado dos `a` seguidas a menos que hagas uso de [`scanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char c[21];
    /* Repetimos hasta obtener la opción correcta (c contenga "a") */
    do {
        printf("Ingrese una letra: \n");
        /* Obtenemos la cadena con un contenido máximo de 20 caracteres */
        scanf("%20s", (char *)c);
    } while (strcmp(c, "a") != 0);
    /* Si se detectó la "a" entonces habremos salido del bucle */
    printf("\nEsta bien\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Es lo que tenia entendido, que cuando uso la funcion getchar(), pero como pide que lea solamente 1, al parecer no tengo manera si no es un string. Capaz entendi mal lo que me pidió que solucione mi profesor. Con string si se que sale porque uso strlen y obligo a que sea 1. Muchas gracias a todos por sus respuestas!

Answer (score 0):

hace un tiempo atras, encontre una implementación de funciones tipo getch (lee por teclado solo un caracter, sin desplegar en pantalla) y getche (lee por teclado solo un caracter, y es desplegado a pantalla) las cuales les cambie el nombre para no tener conflicos de nombres en la compilación, y las ocupe en un desarrollo sobre servidor con Linux Red Hat, y un GNU GCC.

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int lx_getch(void)
{
    struct termios oldattr, newattr;
    int ch;
    tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldattr );
    newattr = oldattr;
    newattr.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON | ECHO );
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newattr );
    ch = getchar();
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldattr );
    return ch;
}

int lx_getche(void)
{
    struct termios oldattr, newattr;
    int ch;
    tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &oldattr );
    newattr = oldattr;
    newattr.c_lflag &= ~( ICANON );
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newattr );
    ch = getchar();
    tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldattr );
    return ch;
}
```

y funcionan de maravilla. Espero te sirva